# MySQL: Merge next duplicate result

Tags: mysql

Hellow I have this query

```
SELECT
ip_clients.client_name, ip_invoice_amounts.invoice_balance as totals
FROM ip_clients
INNER JOIN ip_invoices ON ip_invoices.client_id = ip_clients.client_id
INNER JOIN ip_invoice_items ON ip_invoices.invoice_id = ip_invoice_items.invoice_id
INNER JOIN ip_invoice_amounts ON ip_invoice_items.invoice_id = ip_invoice_amounts.invoice_id
```

example of database
https://pastebin.com/c3iYNMkq

output:

```
| client_name | totals  | 
|------------ | ------- |
| Client 1    | 400.00  |
| Client 2    | 500.00  |
| Client 1    | 124.00  |
```

I want to make this to give **client 1** **524**  and client 2 500
merge the duplicate totals and print them one time with the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` on the `client_name` and a `SUM` on the `invoice_balance` should work:

```
SELECT 
    ip_clients.client_name, 
    SUM(ip_invoice_amounts.invoice_balance) AS totals
FROM ip_clients
    INNER JOIN ip_invoices ON ip_invoices.client_id = ip_clients.client_id
    INNER JOIN ip_invoice_items ON ip_invoices.invoice_id = ip_invoice_items.invoice_id
    INNER JOIN ip_invoice_amounts ON ip_invoice_items.invoice_id = ip_invoice_amounts.invoice_id
GROUP BY ip_clients.client_name
```